# Fastest way to search for terms in a text file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of terms (words), say around 500,000, they are loaded into some data structure, like a Dictionary or Trie perhaps.

In my program I want to open each text document and search for occurrences of these terms.  When i find one I want to stop and transform the string in the text file (replacing it with the transformed string), and continue searching. Once complete with the file, I write to disk the new modified file.

My questions are as follows

1. What would be the best data structure to use for this purpose - a Tree type structure or .NET Dictionary
2. How do i search the text?  Do I break it up into words and compare each chunk against the list I have, or some other method like RegEx, or .NET methods like Contains()?

I'm just looking for some advice on where to start, because I think speed will be really important when I'm dealing with very large and numerous text files.

**EDIT:**  Yes the Transformation is same for each string - based on an algorithm - so each string will look different though. (like for example using a Cipher on the word to make is unreadable.    Anyway I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction, I'm not familiar with many algorithms and data structures out there.

Comment: You're biggest obstacle is going to be the I/O. You can write the most efficient code ever seen and if you have a large number of files and the files are large, it's still going to be a pig.

Comment: Fastest is not always the most maintainable, however if you just split the file and store the terms... idk

Comment: Are your transformations different for each word, or the same? Please provide some practical examples.

Comment: @RedFilter I think this is a brainstorming session.  Maybe better asked on Programmers.SE

Comment: If you have sufficient RAM and the number of files you have is high, try to build a DFA that scans the file from a regex (I don't think there is code to do that in .NET but probably a 3rd party lib?). Building the DFA will take some time, but you can store it to disk and then the runtime through the files should be optimal (one table lookup per byte in the file). But @Tim is right, probably IO will be your real limit anyway.

Comment: DFA = [Deterministic Finite Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

Comment: Another thing to look at would be leveraging the .NET Parallel classes, but again I/O is going to be the limiting factor.

Comment: @Tim I wrote a grep utility and tried Parallel.ForEach - it actually ran a bit slower. i/o was indeed the bottleneck.

Comment: Do you want to only search for whole words or partial words as well?

Comment: The only consideration would be to handle mispellings of the terms.  Levenshtein distance would handle that, but I'm wondering is that one algorithm can handle everything at once, or maybe a modified version?

Answer (score 1):

From a class I took once, I remember we covered a couple of different algorithms. Here are the ones that I remembered to be pretty effective with large text files...

Boyer-Moore:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Knuth-Morris-Pratt:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

These will only help with the lookup, then you can do the manipulation yourself

Answer (score 1):

A hash table ([`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) is going to give you faster lookups than a tree structure. A well-built hash table can find a matching word entry with two or three probes, while a tree structure may require up to an order of magnitude more comparisons.

As for splitting up the words, it would seem to be simple enough to collect all alphabetical characters (and possibly digit characters) up to the next whitespace or punctuation character for each word. You will probably want to convert each word into all-lowercase before looking it up in the dictionary.

Comment: Would the .NET Dictionary(TKey, TValue) Class be a good start?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I suggested.